# Recognize Image through mysql database (facial recognition android development)

Tags: android, database, android-studio, face-recognition

I'm developing an Android application for face recognition.

Is it possible if I'm using the mySql database that the user just saves the image and recognizes through the mySql database?

Comment: No, that is not possible. MySQL can store your images and retrieve them, but it cannot do image processing as part of the retrieval process.

Comment: I see, well if it's so, is it possible if it recognize through a new directory in the application that contains the images that user have taken? thank you for the comment :)

Answer (score 0):

you can compare faces on MySQL storing and comparing the vectors using Euclidean Distance Formula. SQRT( POW(imageVector1 - compareVector1, 2) + POW(imageVector2 - compareVector2, 2) + ...) the lowest value is the more likely to be the person you are looking for.